# PRISMA: How to skip id field in prisma regular type?

Tags: javascript, database, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

Is there any way to skip id in when modeling a prisma type?

```
type User {
  myid: string! @unique
}
```

I have tried this. but is gives,  `✖ One field of the type`User`must be marked as the id field with the`@id`directive.`

actually I want to customize the prisma id.
I dont want to use the default prisma id which always starts with ck---

I want different patterns of id for different types:

for example:
user id : user---abc---123
product id: product---abc---123

Answer (score 3):

the id in any field is supposed to identify it, customizing it won't give you any advantage if you want a uuid you can always use

```
model User {
      myid: String @default(uuid()) @id
}
```

or

```
model User {
      myid: Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
}
```

you can learn more here:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-schema/data-model